# ParsePush.SubscribeAsync(""); Always Throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

im using the library from http://www.parse.com to send Toast Notifications. however by following their tutorial i recive this Error:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued."

So i was wondering if there is any fix to this, or if i should contact them?(av have contacted their help forum which is a lot like Stack Overflow.)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and finally have an answer. But it's not a good one.

It appears there is a bug in the Parse SDK whereby if you declare multiple Extensions in your Application, this error shows up. I managed to prevent the error by going into my Package.appxmanifest file's raw text and removing one of my declared Extensions within the Application tag.

Obviously that is not a suitable workaround, so I'm going to report this to Parse and hope they solve it in the future.